# Automatically paste text boxes from Excel to PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to adjust a VBA script that automatically convert Excel charts into slides of a PowerPoint and then create blank text boxes.

By adjusting the script, I would also like to copy the text boxes inside my worksheet and convert them into text boxes of my PowerPoint's slides. Please consider I have just one text box for each chart so they are always paired.

The script is [available at this link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/08/03/create-powerpoint-presentations-using-excel-vba/) but I paste it here for reference:

```
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

 'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:
    '1. Go to Tools in the VBA menu
    '2. Click on Reference
    '3. Scroll down to Microsoft PowerPoint X.0 Object Library, check the box, and press Okay

    'First we declare the variables we will be using
        Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
        Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

     'Look for existing instance
        On Error Resume Next
        Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    'Let's create a new PowerPoint
        If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
            Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
        End If
    'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
        If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
            newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
        End If

    'Show the PowerPoint
        newPowerPoint.Visible = True

    'Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
        For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

        'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
            newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

        'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
            cht.Select
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
            activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select

        'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
            activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

        'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 15
            newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 125

            activeSlide.Shapes(2).Width = 200
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).Left = 700
            activeSlide.Shapes(2).Top = 125

        Next

    AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
    Set activeSlide = Nothing
    Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

I investigated how to loop the text boxes together with the charts (by using the [Shapes Collection Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223092(v=office.11).aspx)) but that not worked.

Perhaps the *For Each* loop is not correct to use in this case since I want to loop two elements, but I haven't found a way to use a *Do While Loop* using indexes for both the chart and the text box collections.

I believe something easy could made it but my scarce knowledge of VBA is not helping me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code and it is transferring the charts with text boxes successfully, where do you have the problem? Can you at all run the code successfully?

Comment: For what I have seen the text boxes are just created from scratch. Instead I want text boxes in the PowerPoint to  be created using text boxes I create in my worksheet. Therefore they should not be created from scratch rather copy/pasted from my worksheet.

Comment: are you sure that textboxes are not there when you create the slide? It seems it uses a default slide with two text boxes, one for the title, and one for the body. Probably you need to control the objects that exist in the slides when they are created through the code